# I don't know why my app don't stop crashing

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

I'm writing an app which needs the location. Logcat tells me that my code is clear, with no errors. But when I start the app (emulated or on my phone), it crashes.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.a291019;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtLocation = findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            assert locationManager != null;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 10, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.d("GPS", "Latitude" + location.getLatitude() + " et longitude " + location.getLongitude());
                    txtLocation.setText(Log.d("GPS", String.format("Latitude%s et longitude %s", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }

            });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: the relevant part is the error message displayed when your app crashes

Comment: When your app crashes, see the stacktrace in the Logcat window to understand what has happened

Comment: @Bruno , when my app crashes a pop up tell me that it keep stopping and propose me to close the app, once I start the emulation. There's no error message

Comment: Assuming you're a developer, this kind of answer is not acceptable here... Use Android Studio as a developper, especially the Logcat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Move this line to `onCreate` and make it `final`:

```
final TextView txtLocation = findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
```

2) `Log.d()` returns Integer and shouldn't be parameter of `setText` method,
do this instead of that:

```
txtLocation.setText(String.format("Latitude%s et longitude %s", 
    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
package com.example.a291019;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView txtLocation = findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
 getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || 
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        assert locationManager != null;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 10, 
          new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d("GPS", "Latitude" + location.getLatitude() + " et longitude " + 
                    location.getLongitude());
                txtLocation.setText(String.format("Latitude%s et longitude %s", 
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }

        });
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from my point of view the initialization of that line at that position is wrong:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtLocation = findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
```

it has to be placed after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

it is the position where you define the responsible layout for that activity.

So calling `findViewById` for a class member cannot work.

Comment: true. also `Log.d()` returns Integer and shouldn't be parameter of `setText()` method.

Comment: @StefanBeike When I move this line, it doesn't want to emulate my app and there is this message : "error: local variable txtLocation is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final" into the "build" part.

Comment: @Ehsanmsz So how can I set my text with the lattitude and longitude?

Comment: @Vayhuit `txtLocation.setText(String.format("Latitude%s et longitude %s", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));`

Comment: @Ehsanmsz yes but when I add this line, my app still crashing